# Serve Tag not well formed when using EVAL() in OnClientClick event

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to create an onclick event like so

```
onClientClick="document.querySelector('[KPI="31"]').value = '';return false;"
```

The KPI= value has to be data bound, so I use code like so

```
onClientClick="<%# document.querySelector('[KPI=Eval("KPI_ID")]').value = '';return false; %>"
```

But I get an error saying the server code is not well defined. Could anyone help please..

Answer (score 0):

If your datasource is a collection of objects and you are requesting a property called KPI_ID you can avoid using Eval and use Item or Container.DataItem.

Easiest way for me to show this is Container.DataItem, since I don't know what kind of control you are using to bind to. Container.DataItem should be your object, so you only need to cast it to your dataType

```
onClientClick="document.querySelector('[KPI=<%# ((YourDataType)Container.DataItem).KPI_ID %>)]').value = '';return false;"
```

If you use a Repeater in .Net 4.5 you can set the ItemType for the Repeater to your DataType so you can replace ((YourDataType)Container.DataItem) to Item:

```
onClientClick="document.querySelector('[KPI=<%# Item.KPI_ID %>)]').value = '';return false;"
```

If you are not using a property from an object and KPI_ID is a string to use to get the actual value, e.g. if it's in a DataRow, you have to avoid using " in the whole string, without letting the compiler know that it's not the end of the attribute. You can do that by using ' to indicate start and end of attribute and use string.Format so the single quote ' in your javascript is part of the text and the compiler knows it's not the end of the attribute:

```
onClientClick='<%# string.Format("document.querySelector('[KPI={0}]').value = ''; 
return false;", Eval("KPI_ID")) %>'
```

UPDATE:
To support the the additional double quote you can do:

```
onClientClick='<%# string.Format("document.querySelector('[KPI=\"{0}\"]').value = ''; 
return false;", Eval("KPI_ID")) %>'
```

You can replace Eval("KPI_ID") by Item.KPI_ID or ((YourDataType)Container.DataItem).KPI_ID if you wanna avoid using Eval.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'm not sure why using EVAL isn't an option you recommend

Comment: Eval uses string and reflection to get your data. Using a string requires you to understand how to compile javascript with it. I don't like to use strings for properties. If you use properties you can find Usages/References easily and Rename properties without the need to verify everything runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the updated version using EVAL and double quotes, unfortunately I still get an error saying the server tag is not well formed. `<asp:ImageButton ID="ActivityButtonDelete" runat="server" onClientClick='<%# string.Format("document.querySelector('[KPI=\"{0}\")]').value = ''; return false;", Eval("KPI_ID")) %>'
causesvalidation="False"
ImageUrl="~/images/S_B_DELE.gif" ImageAlign="Middle" />`

Comment: I get the same error if I avoid using EVAL and just hardcode the value. `onClientClick='<%# string.Format("document.querySelector('[KPI=\"{0}\")]').value = ''; 
return false;", 31) %>'`

Comment: I removed a ) from my example. But I can't see why it's not well formed other then some Attributes not starting with an uppercase (OnClientClick and CausesValidation). Remove the OnClientClick and check whether the string.Format contains typos, by adding it in your code-behind (with the hardcoded value). (I am on a MacBook and can't verify it in my VS at the moment)